# Refresh a page authenticated by cas went wrong

Tags: java, refresh, single-sign-on, cas

The url changed like below After I authenticated from the cas server .

> http://sso.ecen.com:8080/mip/sys/sys_index.jsp?ticket=ST-2-kHhMa9pYTFuOXVUjJl7x-cas

Error messages come out when I refresh this page.

> org.jasig.cas.client.validation.TicketValidationException: CAS Server could not validate ticket.
>       at org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas10TicketValidator.parseResponseFromServer(Cas10TicketValidator.java:31)
>       at org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractUrlBasedTicketValidator.validate(AbstractUrlBasedTicketValidator.java:165)
>       at org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractTicketValidationFilter.doFilter(AbstractTicketValidationFilter.java:129)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>       at org.jasig.cas.client.authentication.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:103)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>       at ecen.mip.sys.filter.AutoSetUserAdapterFilter.doFilter(AutoSetUserAdapterFilter.java:134)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>       at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>       at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:208)
>       at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:181)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1813)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know why it happened.
You can see [ticket expiration policy](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/Ticket+Expiration+Policy) here. Then you know how to configure the service ticket use time.
Configuration file path:

> cas\WEB-INF\spring-configuration\ticketExpirationPolicies.xml

Answer (score 0):

Probably is because you send a request to http and not https CAS works only with **https**

See what the yalle people say:

> On the mailing lists we often get questions on why SSO does not seem to be working. By default, CAS only sends the single sign on cookie (CASTGC) over secure connections; in other words it is not sent over a plain HTTP channel. Without the SSO cookie CAS requires reauthentication on every request for a service ticket, which explains the lack of SSO behavior. Although it is possible to disable this behavior, we strongly encourage accessing CAS and application entry points over SSL/TLS.

Comment: Are you sure cas only work with https? I've spent a lot of time to getting it to work with http. It runs well except this exception.

Comment: It's possbile access CAS without SSL, but it is not recommended and requires extra configuration.